# Type error converting jts to GeoJSON with feature

Tags: java, gis, geojson

I have a Java POJO "task" with GIS Geometry that I am trying to convert to GeoJSON with Features.

The library I am using to do the conversion is [jts2geojson](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jts2geojson)

My test case code is this, the error is on the String geoJson when I try to pass it into the reader.

```
    GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();
    Double y = -36.829;
    Double x = 174.896;

    Task testTask = new Task();
    testTask.setId(new Long(01));
    testTask.setTitle("Test Task");
    Point p = gf.createPoint(new Coordinate(x, y));
    p.setSRID(4326);
    testTask.setLocation(p);
    taskRepository.save(testTask);

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String geoJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(testTask); // geojson is a String

    GeoJSONReader reader = new GeoJSONReader();
    org.wololo.geojson.Geometry geometry = reader.read(geoJson); // type error

    // create and serialize a FeatureCollection
    List<Feature> features = new ArrayList<Feature>();
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    properties.put("Size", 5);
    properties.put("Area", "Auckland");
    features.add(new Feature(geoJson, properties));
    GeoJSONWriter writer = new GeoJSONWriter();
    GeoJson json = writer.write(features);
```

The issue is the type error on the line org.wololo.geojson.Geometry geometry = reader.read(geoJson);

[image]

It does not accept a string even though the [reader.read](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jts2geojson/blob/aed4ba4a000b6f88f0cb69c2b4fb0ab1fc267f47/src/main/java/org/wololo/jts2geojson/GeoJSONReader.java#L15) method takes a GeoJSON string.

I have also tried passing in a JTS point p:

```
        GeoJSONReader reader = new GeoJSONReader();
    org.wololo.geojson.Geometry geometry = reader.read(p);
```

But that also results in a error in the IDE:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the reader and writer methods around the wrong way. The writer goes from jts.geometry to wololo.geometry.

```
    GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();
    Double y = -36.829;
    Double x = 174.896;

    Task testTask = new Task();
    testTask.setId(new Long(01));
    testTask.setTitle("Test Task");
    Point p = gf.createPoint(new Coordinate(x, y));
    p.setSRID(4326);
    testTask.setLocation(p);
    taskRepository.save(testTask);

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String geoJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(testTask);

    System.out.println(geoJson);

    GeoJSONWriter writer = new GeoJSONWriter();
    org.wololo.geojson.Geometry geom = writer.write(p);

    // create and serialize a FeatureCollection
    List<Feature> features = new ArrayList<Feature>();
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    properties.put("Size", 5);
    properties.put("Area", "Auckland");
    features.add(new Feature(geom, properties));
    GeoJSONWriter writer1 = new GeoJSONWriter();
    FeatureCollection json = writer1.write(features);
```

The writer method converts my point p to a org.wololo.geojson.geometry object which I can then add to a Feature or FeaturesCollection.